# How to run an exe on remote machine using cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, remote

If I want to copy a file on a remote server, I use the following command in cmd:

```
xcopy \\source_file server_ip\path_to_where_the_file_should_go\file.exe
```

The command above works and now I want to run that executable on the server.

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Note: I don't have access to the machine on which this command will be run on, so I won't be able to install any additional application on it, I can just send it a command line script which it will run.

In other words, I have a remote machine on which I am only able to send commands (cmd/Power shell). This machine has an `.exe` which I  copy to another machine using the command above. Now I want to run it on this second machine, from the first machine, using a cmd or power shell script.

Comment: SSH could be a method, do you have SSH client and server on the relevant machines? It should come native with the most recent Windows editions, it is activated with "Add feature...".

Comment: @meJustAndrew .... How about something like .... [`Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -ScriptBlock { COMMAND } -credential USERNAME`](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) which I've had rather good success running. If the exe is on the local drive of the machine, then starting the exe with that sort of logic should do the trick. Permissions will likely be the key though.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be with [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec):

```
psexec \\server_ip "path_to_where_the_file_should_go/file.exe"
```

---

Other methods include remote Powershell, telnet, SSH.

Comment: I have seen this solution on the internet, but the problem is that I am unable to install additional applications (like `PsExec`) on the target machine...

Comment: What do you mean by *install*? It's a simple executable to be run locally.

Comment: I mean that I am running this command as part of a VSTS release pipeline, and the command will be run on a random machine which needs to connect to a server and to run the *file.exe*. I don't have rights to connect to any of these machines which will need to run `psexec` in order to make sure that the psexec is there...

Answer (score 0):

What about running that command through Task Scheduler, which is built-in at any Windows?

[image: Remote control via Task Scheduler]